# is there any Javascript Libraries for excel based tables that allow for individual cell types

Tags: javascript

I have a editable table where i am currently showing the data in Columns rather than rows, i have some cells in this table that need to be drop downs and some that need to be check boxes.

```
--------------
|    |User X  | 
|Name|Text    |
|Age |Text    |
|Date|Date    |
|Sex |Dropdown|
```

The libraries i found set the cell type by Column and keep the drop down options stored in a source linked to the column i would really like a library that lets you do this cell by cell but will settle foe one that lets for rows. i have already looked at Jexcel and Tabulator and looking through my searches they all seem to do the same